# Crystal Reports in VS 2010: "Database logon failed" error while trying printing a document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

recently I went from CR Basic for `VS2008`, to `CR 13.0.2 (for VS 2010)` on `Windows 7 (64 bit)` and Iam using .NET 4.5 framework.

In `VS2008` all was working fine, now I get the "Database logon failed" error, and **I DO NOT use any database**. I only fill Parameter and Formula fields on the Crystal Report, and try to print it out. As mentioned, in VS 2008 all was woking OK, now its not. Why so??

Here is my simple code:

```
//passing data to parameters like (one example):
cr1.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", Actual_Parameter);

//and my code for prinitng:
PrintDocument doctoprint = new PrintDocument();
doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = objPrinter.Value.ToString();
cr1.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.DefaultPaperSize;
CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins margins = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
cr1.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(margins);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
cr1.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);  //and here i get the error!
```

Can someone help me out? I really have no idea what to do.
Mitja

Comment: [Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167127/database-logon-failed-error-after-upgrading-from-vs-2008-to-vs-2010) might help.

Comment: Found that thread before, put that code into app.config file, but the same error, sorry.